# Nativescript class implementing observables default setter behaviour

Tags: typescript, nativescript

I am taking a look at the [nativescript hello world typescript](https://github.com/NativeScript/template-hello-world-ts) repo and I have come across something kind of tedious working with nativescript's implementation of observables.

If you look at how the [view model](https://github.com/NativeScript/template-hello-world-ts/blob/release/main-view-model.ts) is defined you can see that it is a class that simply extends the `Observable` library. Whenever you are defining a `setter` method for a property, 
you **manually** need to call `super.notifyPropertyChange("propertyName", propertyValue);`

IMHO this procedure **is very inefficient and error prone** if you have view models with many properties.

Is there a way to automate this task? ( Maybe with a base class that tells any setter to `notifyPropertyChange` ? )
If not, how are you handling this problem? Are there other implementations of the `Observable` mechanism?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is what I have been using in couple of production apps:

```
import { Observable } from "data/observable";

export class ObservableModel extends Observable {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    public get(propertyName: string) {
        return this["_" + propertyName];
    }

    public set(propertyName: string, value) {
        if (this["_" + propertyName] === value) {
            return;
        }

        this["_" + propertyName] = value;
        this.refresh(propertyName);
    }

    public refresh(propertyName: string) {
        super.notify({
            eventName: Observable.propertyChangeEvent,
            propertyName,
            object: this,
            value: this["_" + propertyName],
        });
    }
}
```

Then your models look something like:

```
export class LoginViewModel extends ObservableModel {
    get userName(): string { return this.get("userName"); }
    set userName(val: string) { this.set("userName", val); }

    get password(): string { return this.get("password"); }
    set password(val: string) { this.set("password", val); }
}
```

And when you need to work with the values you just use:

```
const vm = new LoginViewModel();
vm.userName = "jdoe";
vm.password = "$3cr3T";
```

**UPDATE**
Decorator implementation:

```
export function ObservableProperty() {
    return (target: Observable, propertyKey: string) => {
        Object.defineProperty(target, propertyKey, {
            get: function () {
                return this["_" + propertyKey];
            },
            set: function (value) {
                if (this["_" + propertyKey] === value) {
                    return;
                }

                this["_" + propertyKey] = value;
                this.notify({
                    eventName: Observable.propertyChangeEvent,
                    propertyName: propertyKey,
                    object: this,
                    value,
                });
            },
            enumerable: true,
            configurable: true
        });
    };
}
```

Model:

```
export class LoginViewModel extends Observable {
    @ObservableProperty() public userName: string;
    @ObservableProperty() public password: string;
}
```

Comment: @PeterStaev decorator factories, e.g. `@ObservableProperty()`, are more even more complex than decorators, e.g. @ObservableProperty. Consider using a plain old decorator. See my answer for an example of a plain old decorator

Comment: @PeterStaev Thank you, it works great! One quick question, why do you need to prefix the key with "_" ?

Comment: @AaronUllal, this is in order not to use the create by the decorator property. Otherwise it will become and endless recursion because `this[propertyKey]` is basically the same as using the property (for example `this["userName"]` is the same as `this.userName`)

Comment: @PeterStaev why not just store the actual value in a very well captured by the accessors? That way you completely avoid polluting the namespace of this

Comment: @AluanHaddad could you elaborate? Sounds good I also prefer not to use "this"

Comment: Just create a variable inside the Decorator function, right before the `Object.defineProperty` call. Then have `get` and `set` read from and write to this variable. There's no need to use `this` at all because `get` and `set` close over the variable.

Comment: @AluanHaddad I'm coming from an object oriented world, where properties are backed up by private variables that contain the actual values. I do not like the "hidden" approach where the actual value is stored somewhere in some variable in a closure. But if you prefer the closure way it is possible.

Comment: @PeterStaev I thought encapsulation was important in OOP. Guess it is all about syntax...

Comment: @PeterStaev sorry I realize my remarks sounds sarcastic and I am sorry. However, in all seriousness, I believe that my approach adheres much more strongly to the SOLID design principles than this. Consider all of the actors involved including the decorated class, the resulting instance, the decorator itself, any deriving classes, and any consumers of the instance. As far as familiarity is concerned, it all depends on which other languages you know. In C# the use of closures is so idiomatic that we don't even consider it most of the time.

Comment: The annotation works like a charm! I saved the annotation definition in another .ts file and imported in the model class.

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed verbose and error prone. It is a violation of DRY and should be avoided. There are lots of ways to accomplish this cleanly using JavaScript.

One way might be to use a decorator to automatically wire up all of the boilerplate in a generic manner and keep the model class clean and declarative.

For example we could create the following function

**observed.ts**

```
export default function<T extends Notifier<T, K>, K extends keyof T>(target: T, key: K) {
  let storedValue = target[key];

  const get = () => storedValue;

  const set = (value: T[K]) => {
    if (storedValue !== value) {
      storedValue = value;
      target.notifyPropertyChange(key, storedValue);
    }
  };

  Object.defineProperty(target, key, {
    get,
    set,
    enumerable: true,
    configurable: false
  });
}

export interface Notifier<T, K extends keyof T> {
  notifyPropertyChange(key: K, value: T[K]): void;
}
```

Now we can use it to remove all of the boilerplate from the model itself. We even remove the getters and setters and use simple properties

**model.ts**

```
// Stub observable class to verify inheritance works correctly (as requested)
class Observable {
  notifyPropertyChange(key: string, value: {}) {
    console.log(`from super: ${key} ===> ${value}`);
  }
}

export class Model extends Observable {

import observed from './observed';

export class Model extends Observable {
  @observed name = 'Bob';

  @observed age = 38;

  @observed birthdate = moment();

  notifyPropertyChange<K extends keyof this>(key: K, value: this[K]): void {
    super.notifyPropertyChange(key, value);
    console.log(`${key} ===> ${value}}`);
  }
}

const model = new Model();

model.name = 'Rob';

model.name = 'Robert';
```

Some of the benefits of this approach are that

- It is rather DRY
- We have an even more concise and readable model class than if we defined getters and setters manually
- Our decorator improves type checking by requiring that the class provides a `notifyPropertyChange` method and that it gets called on the correct property keys. If we violate this, TypeScript will issue a compiler error
- The actual variable that is used to store the value is truly private. It is only in scope within the decorator's closure and cannot be accessed except through the getter and setter. This is not a naming convention, it is true privacy, the good old fashioned JavaScript way
- we avoid the introduction of a base class solely for code sharing. That is we can prefer composition to inheritance
- we gain the convenience of inline initializers and the resulting type inference

This could be generalized to decorate an entire class, making it even DRYer.

Comment: I like this approach! I'll try it out :) Thanks

Comment: I just realized that I had a typo that I just fixed. I tested this, but then renamed a few things to fit on a single line for stackoverflow format and missed a name.

Comment: The problem with this approach however is that, because the decorator gets called before when the class gets declared, in the notifyPropertyChange method I cannot call super().notifyPropertyChange,which would be the wanted behaviour

Comment: @AaronUllal see my updated answer, you just need to call super via delegation.

Comment: @AaronUllal can you be more specific? You need TypeScript >= 2.2 and `"experimentalDecorators": true` in tsconfig.json. What error do you receive?

Comment: Ohh! I am on ts 2.1.6. experimentalDecorators is on...let me upgrade and see

Comment: In theory it should also working in that version but you might as well get the latest anyway. If you can tell me more about the error you're getting I might be able to help. Is it a TypeScript error or is it a runtime error?

Comment: It's a runtime error, basically it says super is undefined so it cannot find the method notifyPropertyChange...I'll run it again and give you exact stack trace

Comment: OK, I just tested with an arbitrary base class having a dummy `notifyPropertyChange` method. It works perfectly fine. Sounds like you have a bad import somewhere. Make sure your super class is imported correctly. I used `import {Observable} from 'data/observable';` because it was in the NativeScript sample app on GitHub. I added stub to example, verifies approach works with `super`